# How to properly drain a Queue with a fast producer?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, tibco, tibco-ems

I have a situation where I am in need to drain a JMS (specifically Tibco EMS) queue. The use case is if we were to take a large outage, the queue would build up and processing it would take far too long. So rather, we want to drain the queue, and perform a coldstart type routine to get current state.

The code I have so far to do this is as follows:

```
 int count = 0;
    Message msg = null;
    while ((msg = connection.receive(timeout)) != null) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count + " msgs removed from queue: " + queueName);
```

Basically it loops receiving messages until `timeout` expires before a message is received, indicating the queue is empty.

My question deals with this value of `timeout`. Suppose we have a very fast producer on the queue, setting a timeout of say 500ms seems a bit arbitrary. It is possible that we will loop indefinitely (i.e. the producer produces >= 1 message every 500ms)

The alternative is to use receiveNoWait(). This, to my understanding, pulls a message if it is available, or returns null, with no timeout involved. However, according to **[THIS](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/11384-draining-a-jms-queue-using-spring-1-2-6)** article:

> Not all JMS providers return immediately with a message if you call receiveNoWait() and there may be messages on the broker, so its worth waiting a second or so just to be sure the queue really is drained.

So is there a more robust way to do this from a programmatic approach? Alternatively is there a drain function that comes with Tibco EMS admin?

Answer (score 3):

In TIBCO EMS Admin you can simply issue the command

```
PURGE QUEUE <queue name>
```

to remove all messages from it. For multiple queues, you can do

```
PURGE ALL QUEUES <pattern using '>' and '*' as wildcards>
```

Note that the command line interface of EMS Admin aside, there is also a Java-API to issue such Admin commands directly from inside a Java program.

Answer (score 0):

You can set expiry on the message if the message is not required after a particular period of time. This will ensure that the message goes off the queue after expiry. A simple receive() call with a timeout can be used in addition to the expiry. Receive will work if there are messages in the queue. If the message is in non-committed state or locked by some process, only then the receive call wouldn't be able to get that message.